# Does Haskell support closed polymorphic types?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, ghc

Given:

```
newtype PlayerHandle = PlayerHandle Int deriving (Show)
newtype MinionHandle = MinionHandle Int deriving (Show)
newtype WeaponHandle = WeaponHandle Int deriving (Show)
```

In the following code, I would like `handle` to be *exactly* one of three types: `PlayerHandle`, `MinionHandle`, and `WeaponHandle`. Is this possible to do in Haskell?

```
data Effect where
    WithEach :: (??? handle) => [handle] -> (handle -> Effect) -> Effect -- Want `handle' to be under closed set of types.
```

The following is too tedious:

```
data Effect' where
    WithEachPlayer :: [PlayerHandle] -> (PlayerHandle -> Effect) -> Effect
    WithEachMinion :: [MinionHandle] -> (MinionHandle -> Effect) -> Effect
    WithEachWeapon :: [WeaponHandle] -> (WeaponHandle -> Effect) -> Effect
```

EDIT:

Ørjan Johansen has proposed using closed type families, which indeed gets me a step closer to what I want. The issue I'm having using them is that I can't seem to write the following:

```
type family IsHandle h :: Constraint where
    IsHandle (PlayerHandle) = ()
    IsHandle (MinionHandle) = ()
    IsHandle (WeaponHandle) = ()

data Effect where
    WithEach :: (IsHandle handle) => [handle] -> (handle -> Effect) -> Effect

enactEffect :: Effect -> IO ()
enactEffect (WithEach handles cont) = forM_ handles $ \handle -> do
    print handle  -- Eeek! Can't deduce Show, despite all cases being instances of Show.
    enactEffect $ cont handle
```

Here GHC complains that it cannot deduce that the handle is an instance of `Show`. I am hesitant to solve this by moving the `Show` constraint in the `WithEach` constructor for various reasons. These include modularity and scalability. Would something like a closed data family solve this (as I know type family mappings are not injective... Is that the problem even with closed ones?)

Comment: I find this highly interesting and you got my upvote already but I hope you don't mind the question: why not just use a sum-type for your handlers - I'm sure you have your reasons but the example here seems to scream for this basic solution.

Comment: @Carsten: Mostly because I hoped there was a better way. I'd never used closed type families before (I forgot GHC already supported them). At this point, I think I might just use the three different constructors and when pattern matching them, I can pass them directly to `enactEffect :: (Show h) => [h] -> (h -> Effect) -> IO ()`. This will allow me to handle more complex constraints than `Show` (assuming `Show` is a prerequisite for `WithEach` constructor), including module private ones.

Comment: as long as you don't want to extent to other handler IMO there is no *better* way [this](https://gist.github.com/CarstenKoenig/9c7354b88befcc1db1d8) seems to be a lot easier (to me ;) )

Comment: @Carsten: I see what you are saying. I really want to enforce static types. I'm using this for my DSL Hearthstone model (effects and abilities). This will rule out illegal card constructions that a sum type would permit.

Comment: ah ok - sorry for the buzz

Comment: @Thomas Eding: can't you just hide the sum type itself, to rule out illegal card constructions?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: That loses some necessary type info. For example, I dont want to allow clients to do something like DestroyMinion when constructed with a bad instance of a sum type . To see my real use case, refer to dreadInfernal definition in https://github.com/thomaseding/hearthshroud/blob/a4f424289878baaa6094cb94d8dc2028e8d1aa3d/src/Hearth/Cards/Basic.hs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the solutions guys. They all are helpful for various use cases. For my use case, it turned out that making the handle types into a single GADT solved my problem.

Here's my derived solution for those interested:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

data Player
data Minion
data Weapon

data Handle a where
    PlayerHandle :: Int -> Handle Player
    MinionHandle :: Int -> Handle Minion
    WeaponHandle :: Int -> Handle Weapon

data Effect where
    WithEach :: [Handle h] -> (Handle h -> Effect) -> Effect
    PrintSecret :: Handle h -> Effect

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Pretend the below code is a separate file that imports the above data types
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ObtainSecret a where
    obtainSecret :: a -> String

instance ObtainSecret (Handle a) where
    obtainSecret = \case
        PlayerHandle n -> "Player" ++ show n
        MinionHandle n -> "Minion" ++ show n
        WeaponHandle n -> "Weapon" ++ show n

enactEffect :: Effect -> IO ()
enactEffect = \case
    WithEach handles continuation -> mapM_ (enactEffect . continuation) handles
    PrintSecret handle -> putStrLn (obtainSecret handle)

createEffect :: [Handle h] -> Effect
createEffect handles = WithEach handles PrintSecret

main :: IO ()
main = do
    enactEffect $ createEffect $ map PlayerHandle [0..2]
    enactEffect $ createEffect $ map MinionHandle [3..5]
    enactEffect $ createEffect $ map WeaponHandle [6..9]
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you can get precisely your syntax with a [closed](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/type-families.html#closed-type-families) [constraint](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/constraint-kind.html) type family:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds, GADTs #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

newtype PlayerHandle = PlayerHandle Int
newtype MinionHandle = MinionHandle Int
newtype WeaponHandle = WeaponHandle Int

type family IsHandle h :: Constraint where
    IsHandle (PlayerHandle) = ()
    IsHandle (MinionHandle) = ()
    IsHandle (WeaponHandle) = ()

data Effect where
    WithEach :: (IsHandle handle) => [handle] -> (handle -> Effect) -> Effect
```

EDIT: Another attempt that includes `Show`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds, GADTs,
             UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
import Control.Monad (forM_)

newtype PlayerHandle = PlayerHandle Int
newtype MinionHandle = MinionHandle Int
newtype WeaponHandle = WeaponHandle Int

type family IsHandle' h :: Constraint where
    IsHandle' (PlayerHandle) = ()
    IsHandle' (MinionHandle) = ()
    IsHandle' (WeaponHandle) = ()

type IsHandle h = (IsHandle' h, Show h)

data Effect where
    WithEach :: (IsHandle handle) => [handle] -> (handle -> Effect) -> Effect

-- Assume my each (IsHandle a) already is an instance of a class I want to use, such as (Show).
enactEffect :: Effect -> IO ()
enactEffect (WithEach handles cont) = forM_ handles $ \handle -> do
    print handle  -- (*)
    enactEffect $ cont handle
```

I don't quite see how to avoid having two different classes, types or families and get the API you seem to want without making it possible to add other types in another module. I also don't know of any way for the resulting `IsHandle` constraint to automatically inherit all the classes the three types have in common, without you listing them *somewhere*.

But I think depending on your needs/style, there are some more options similar to my last one:

- You could make `IsHandle` a class with `IsHandle'` and `Show` etc. as superclasses.
- You could make `IsHandle'` a class, in which case the only prevention against adding more types would be not exporting `IsHandle'`.

One advantage of the last one is that it can seriously cut down the number of extensions needed for this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, ConstraintKinds #-}

class IsHandle' h
instance IsHandle' (PlayerHandle)
instance IsHandle' (MinionHandle)
instance IsHandle' (WeaponHandle)

type IsHandle h = (IsHandle' h, Show h)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution based on GADTs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}
module GADThandle where

import Control.Monad

newtype PlayerHandle = PlayerHandle Int deriving (Show)
newtype MinionHandle = MinionHandle Int deriving (Show)
newtype WeaponHandle = WeaponHandle Int deriving (Show)

data HandleW a where
   WPlayer :: HandleW PlayerHandle
   WMinion :: HandleW MinionHandle
   WWeapon :: HandleW WeaponHandle

handlewShow :: HandleW a -> (Show a => b) -> b
handlewShow WPlayer x = x
handlewShow WMinion x = x
handlewShow WWeapon x = x

data Effect where
   WithEach :: HandleW handle -> [handle] -> (handle -> Effect) -> Effect 

enactEffect :: Effect -> IO ()
enactEffect (WithEach handlew handles cont) = handlewShow handlew $ 
   forM_ handles $ \handle -> do
      print handle
      enactEffect $ cont handle
```

The idea here is to use a type witness `HandleW a`, certifying that `a` is one of your three types. Then, the "lemma" `handlewShow` proves that if `HandleW a` holds, then `a` must be a `Show`-able type.

It is also possible to generalize the code above to arbitrary type classes. The lemma below proves that if you have `c T` for each of your three types `T`, and you know that `HandleW a` holds, then `c a` must hold as well. You can obtain the previous lemma by picking `c = Show`.

```
handlewC :: (c PlayerHandle, c MinionHandle, c WeaponHandle) => 
   HandleW a -> Proxy c -> (c a => b) -> b
handlewC WPlayer Proxy x = x
handlewC WMinion Proxy x = x
handlewC WWeapon Proxy x = x

enactEffect' :: Effect -> IO ()
enactEffect' (WithEach handlew handles cont) = handlewC handlew (Proxy :: Proxy Show) $ 
   forM_ handles $ \handle -> do
      print handle
      enactEffect' $ cont handle
```

Comment: If you add a `class Handle a where { handlew :: p a -> HandleW a }` and instances `instance Handle PlayerHandle where { handlew _ = WPlayer }`, etc., you can get rid of passing around the `HandleW` witness manually and match the desired syntax exactly.

Comment: Looks promising. I'll try it out when I get the chance.

Answer (score 4):

Add a type parameter to your `Handle` type, and restrict its values to be one of just three using `DataKinds`, thus:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs          #-}

import Control.Monad

data Entity = Player | Minion | Weapon

newtype Handle (e :: Entity) = Handle Int
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

data Effect where
    WithEach :: [Handle e] -> (Handle e -> Effect) -> Effect

enactEffect :: Effect -> IO ()
enactEffect (WithEach handles cont) = forM_ handles $ \handle -> do
    print handle
    enactEffect $ cont handle
```

Comment: This works for exactly what I need. I don't need to use DataKinds (I can use types instead), but the end result is the same.

Comment: @ThomasEding I'm guessing that by "I can use types instead", you mean "I can write `data Player; data Minion; data Weapon; newtype Handle e = Handle Int`". Beware the difference between the two: with yours, `Handle :: * -> *`, and therefore can be applied to any dumb old type like `Handle ()` or `Handle Bool`; with mine, `Handle :: Entity -> *`, and therefore the kind-checker will enforce that `Handle` is *only* applied to one of the three types you care about.

Comment: I also create three distinct monomorphic constructors for each of the handle varieties. I have posted my derived solution in my question.

Comment: @ThomasEding Standard practice is to put solutions as answers, not as questions. It's considered perfectly fine to write and accept an answer to your own question.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll accept my answer when SO allows me to do so (several hours from now).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to do something complex with the type, I would go with a simple solution using `class`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Control.Monad

newtype PlayerHandle = PlayerHandle Int deriving (Show)
newtype MinionHandle = MinionHandle Int deriving (Show)
newtype WeaponHandle = WeaponHandle Int deriving (Show)

class (Show h) => Handle h
instance Handle PlayerHandle
instance Handle MinionHandle
instance Handle WeaponHandle

data Effect where
    WithEach :: (Handle handle) => [handle] -> (handle -> Effect) -> Effect

enactEffect :: Effect -> IO ()
enactEffect (WithEach handles cont) = forM_ handles $ \handle -> do
    print handle
    enactEffect $ cont handle
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I do not know all the class constraints I'll need to add to the `Handle` class at the time I would define the `Handle` class. Ideally consumers of `Handle` would be able to create new classes that Player/Minion/WeaponHandle will all instantiate and use with a generic `Handle`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use GADTs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, GADTs, RankNTypes, DataKinds #-}

data K = Player | Minion | Weapon
  deriving (Eq, Show)

newtype PlayerHandle = PlayerHandle Int deriving (Show)
newtype MinionHandle = MinionHandle Int deriving (Show)
newtype WeaponHandle = WeaponHandle Int deriving (Show)

-- Plain ADT might be enough
-- see below
data Handle (k :: K) where
  PlayerHandle' :: PlayerHandle -> Handle Player
  MinionHandle' :: MinionHandle -> Handle Minion
  WeaponHandle' :: WeaponHandle -> Handle Weapon

data SomeHandle where
  SomeHandle :: Handle k -> SomeHandle

data Effect where
  WithEach :: (SomeHandle -> IO ()) -> Effect

printEffect :: Effect
printEffect = WithEach f
  where f (SomeHandle h) = g h
        g :: Handle k -> IO ()
        g (PlayerHandle' p) = putStrLn $ "player :" ++ show p
        g (MinionHandle' p) = putStrLn $ "minion :" ++ show p
        g (WeaponHandle' p) = putStrLn $ "weapon :" ++ show p

-- GADTs are useful, if you want to have maps preserving handle kind:
data HandleMap where
  -- HandleMap have to handle all `k`, yet cannot change it!
  HandleMap :: (forall k. Handle k -> Handle k) -> HandleMap

zeroWeaponHandle :: HandleMap
zeroWeaponHandle = HandleMap f
  where f :: forall k. Handle k -> Handle k
        f (PlayerHandle' h) = PlayerHandle' h
        f (MinionHandle' h) = MinionHandle' h
        f (WeaponHandle' _) = WeaponHandle' $ WeaponHandle 0
```

Comment: Looks promising. I'll try it out when I get the chance.